# char pointer as function parameter

Tags: c, sizeof

I have a function A that has a `char *` parameter. In `A()`, I use `sizeof` to calculate the size of buf , but I got 8 in i686 machine and 4 in armel machine. why is not  it  128? The snippet is as below:

```
void A(char *p)
{
    printf("sizeof p is %d\n", sizeof(p));
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf[128];
    printf("sizeof buf is %d\n", sizeof(buf));
    A(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

the result is like this(in i686):

```
sizeof buf is 128
sizeof p is 8
```

Please tell me the reason.

Comment: Don't use %d for sizeof(), use %zu instead. %d just causes troubles with sizeof() as it's size_t not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you print the size of the *pointer*, and not what it points to. Arrays decays to pointers, and as soon as you pass it to a function you have a pointer instead, and loose all size information of the original array.

Comment: that is to say, in the function i cannot get the size infomation, except for adding a size parameter. right?

Answer (score 2):

- In `main()` function, `buf` is an array, so `sizeof buf` gives the size of this array: `sizeof(char[128])` (128 bytes).  That's because an array is not *converted* to a pointer when used as operand of `sizeof` operator.
- In `A()` function, `p` is a pointer, so `sizeof p` gives the size of this pointer: `sizeof(char *)` (8 bytes on your implementation).

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(buf)` is `128*sizeof(buf[0])` and sizeof(p) is just `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: +1 for `128*sizeof(buf[0]);`. Actually no one had given the emphasis on the point that in case of arrays,sizeof actually returns the `(arraysize)* (bytes needed for the datatype)`.

Answer (score 0):

When passed into function, it decays to an ordinary pointer that has size of your native size(4 or 8).

Use strlen() because it checks for a "null" at the end and gives correct size if the array is already initalized.