# Behaviour of sizeof() operator

Tags: c++, c, string, char, sizeof

For the following piece of code:

```
char a[] = "Apple";
char *s[] = {"Apple"};
printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(s[0]));
```

The output is:

```
6 4
```

Can someone tell me why `sizeof()` is giving different outputs?

**EDIT:** I did intend to type `sizeof()` originally, but typed `strlen()` instead. I apologize for the same. I have edited the statement now.

Comment: Err… maybe because you use `strlen` for `s[0]` (which doesn't count the 0-terminator)… (`sizeof s[0]`, however, would give `sizeof(char *)`)

Comment: Because the second test is not sizeof, but strlen? strlen does not include the terminating null character. Even if it was sizeof, however, it would return the size of the pointer to the string.

Comment: @mafso Oops! My bad. I have edited the question statement. I did intend to write sizeof() only.

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672162/sizeof-arrays-and-pointers) and maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424078/char-pointer-as-function-parameter). And `char *s[] = {"Apple"};` is (besides the additional identifier) equivalent to `char *tmp = "Apple"; char *s[] = { tmp };` not (what you seem to assume) to `char s[][6] = { "Apple" };` (cf. second part of my last comment). Related: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html. And last not least: Use `%zu` to print `size_t` variables, `%d` is for `int` (and `sizeof` yields an object of type `size_t`).

Comment: -1 for changing the question!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(a)` is the size of the array, which contains the terminator as well as the 5 printable characters.

`strlen(s[0])` gives the length of the string, excluding the terminator, since that is what `strlen` is specified to do.

UPDATE: `sizeof(s[0])` is the size of a pointer. There's no way to determine the size of an array given just a pointer to it.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` gives you the number of `char`s allocated to `a` while  `strlen` gives you the length of useable string in `a`.

Answer (score 3):

the `\0` counts as part of the size in memory of the string, but the length of the string itself, given by `strlen()`, is only given by the characters before the `\0` is encountered.

Answer (score 3):

A character array declared like this:

```
char a[] = "Apple";
```

has, according to the language specification, a null-terminator. Therefore, the length of the array is 6. There are 5 characters, and then the null terminator.

On the other hand, `strlen()` returns the number of characters that precede the null terminator. Which is 5.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand.

In this statement

```
char a[] = "Apple";
```

array a is initialized by characters of string literal "Apple" that includes the terminating zero.
In fact this record is equivalent to

```
char a[] = { 'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', '\0'; };
```

So the size in bytes of a is equal to 6.

Standard C function `strlen` counts symbols in a string until it encounters the terminating zero. So

strlen( a )

will return 5 that is the number of characters in the array that are before the terminating zero.

Take into account that you could write for example

```
char a[100] = "Apple";
```

In this case `sizeof( a )` will yield 100 because you explicitly specified the number of bytes that the array will occupy. However it was initialized only with 6 characters of the string literal. So how to find how many actual data are in the character array? For this purpose function `strlen` was introduced that to distinguish the size of a character array and the number of actual data in the character array.

Answer (score 1):

Because in C there is no string type.  String is a character array which is NULL terminated. strlen() counts the characters until the NULL character, whereas sizeof() actually returns the amount of memory used up by the charater array.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is an array of `char`s, which contains 6 elements, hence `sizeof` returns 6 (the length of the string including zero termination).

`s` is an array of pointers to `char`. The pointer size is 4 bytes. `sizeof(s[0])` returns the size of the first element, which is pointer, i.e. its size is 4.

Answer (score 1):

When you define:

> char a[] = "Apple";

It means an array of characters, which equals to the following definition:

> char a[] = {'A', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', '\0'};   // '\0' is the string termination character which equals to 0

Since char type size is 1, the sizeof(a) returns 6 which is the size of the whole array.

Nevertheless, when you define:

> char *s[] = {"Apple"};

It means an array of **char pointer**. Hence sizeof(s[0]) return the size of its first element which
equals to sizeof(char*).
For a 32-bit platform, sizeof(char*) = 4. If you do it on an 64-bit platform, 8 is the expected value.